# DB2 installation error while installing portlet server

Tags: java, db2, portlet, websphere-portal

I am getting DB2 error while installing Portlet Server on my machine.

```
 [exec] + db2 "UPDATE DBM CFG USING sheapthres 0" 
 [exec] DB20000I  The UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION command completed 
 [exec] successfully.

 [exec] + db2 -v "CREATE DB wpsdb USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US PAGESIZE 8192" 
 [exec] CREATE DB wpsdb USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US PAGESIZE 8192
 [exec] SQL1092N  "PJAMI" does not have the authority to perform the requested command 
 [exec] or operation.
```

Error log [log file URL](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5fzF8vSIxGBeWNLcEJHR3pqUzA)

I am the administrator for my machine. [image: Click here for screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you are the administrator of your machine. DB2 relies on the OS security mechanism for the authentication step. However, the authorization step is inside DB2. It means, that DB2 has several levels of security, and your user does not belong to the most important.

In order to create a database, you have to check the authority needed in the documentation: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001941.html

As you can see, only users belonging to SYSADM or SYSCTRL can create databases; But now, you can ask where are those authorities defined? Well, those authorities are defined at instance level associating a OS group for them. You run the command:

```
db2 get dbm cfg | grep GROUP
```

And you will see the groups. If your user does not belong to one of those groups, your user won't be able to create the database.

In order to know the groups you belong to:

```
id
```

In order to change the group, you need to be root

```
sudo su vi /etc/group
```

In order to change the DB2 authorities, you need to have SYSADM authority or be switch to the instance owner:

```
su - db2inst1
db2 update dbm cfg using SYSADM_GROUP db2admins
```

Answer (score 0):

When your machine is part of a Windows domain, then the default is for DB2 to enumerate the groups that a particular ID belongs to based on where the ID is defined.  Therefore, DB2 will ask the domain controller for domain IDs, and the local machine for local IDs.

So in your case, even though your `PJAMI` ID has administrator privileges on the local machine, DB2 asked the domain controller what groups you belong to instead of the local machine.

There are 2 ways to resolve this:

1. Set the DB2 Registry Variable `DB2_GRP_LOOKUP` to `LOCAL`

   ```
   db2set DB2_GRP_LOOKUP=LOCAL
   ```

   This will instruct DB2 to always use the local machine to enumerate groups for a user, regardless of whether the ID is defined in the domain or the local machine.

   You have to restart the DB2 instance in order for this to take effect.
2. Use a different ID (like the db2admin ID that was probably created during installation) that exists on your local machine and has sufficient privileges.

Note: @AngocA's answer regarding verifying the settings for `SYSADM_GROUP` etc is correct; but note that on Windows by default `SYSADM_GROUP` is blank.  When this is the case, DB2 uses the local machine's `Administrators` group as `SYSADM_GROUP`.